# Why is my hair dynamics going crazy?

Tags: animation, particles, transforms, hair

**Here is my model, with a baked walking animation.**

[image]

As you can see the hair is doing some wild things, is the scale of my model the problem?
I am using vertex groups for the hair particle systems, there is two. Left scalp and right scalp (shown below).

At 300 particles on each side, the hair freaks out with or without children.
I could really use some help on this, I have tried various things like:

- Add collision modifiers
- Changing the particle settings (with/without children etc)
- Redoing particle systems from scratch

But I am still at a loss, so the last idea I have is that the model scale is too low for the dynamic hair to work properly.

[image: Mid Walk]
But same thing happens when scale is at 1, no children, clothes on (they have collision modifier on).
[image]

Should I use the other method of using separated scalp as the emitter instead of the model mesh itself?
Any and all help is appreciated

Comment: David, could you possibly post a stripped-down version of your file to "blender-exchange.com"?   Only include the mesh containing the Hair PS.  It will then give you HTML that you can edit your question and paste in the link.   Long hair can be a challenge.

Comment: Try rendering *without* baking.   There is a known issue....  https://developer.blender.org/T98599

Comment: I've edited the question to include the skimmed-down blend file. Thank you for that. I will try a render without baking like you suggest as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a starter towards things to consider: [image]

1. increasing pin-goal Strength to 1.0 from 0 makes the biggest difference.  This has a bit to do with behavior around the root.
2. increasing damping from 0.5 to 8 (play with this)
3. Fix my incorrect change:  change B-Spline back on and set back to 6.  This is a good thing to have.
4. impulse clamping from 0 to 1  or higher (may or may not help depending on other Effectors you may have).  This is also important to consider in Cloth simulations where you have a complex (character) collision mesh
5. sometimes I find increasing Gravity Field Weight from 1 to something higher, or to play around with Vertex Mass (try 5kg instead or your 0.3 kg)

[image]

result where there's only changes on the left side Hair:

[image]

Also:

6. try (in Volume) changing Internal Friction from 0 to 0.5

There are (unfortunately) a *lot* of knobs and dials to experiment with!