# Hair breaks when I apply 'Hair Dynamics'

Tags: hair

[image]

So making my first model from scratch, I give my lil guy a mohawk, but when I go to apply Hair dynamics it breaks apart like this.
I have no clue how to fix/what I've done wrong. any help please?

Comment: maybe read this answer? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265824/why-is-my-hair-dynamics-going-crazy